# Call provider service in pouchDb gives "TypeError: Cannot set property 'itemsList' of undefined"

Tags: angular, ionic3, pouchdb

When calling the `CommonServiceProvider` in pouchdb callback, instead of giving contacts details it gives Error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'itemsList' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot set property 'itemsList' of undefined

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
import { CommonServiceProvider } from '../../providers/common-service/common-service';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-contact-lists',
  templateUrl: 'contact-lists.html',
})
export class ContactListsPage {
  public itemsList;
  searchQuery: string = '';
  private db;
  constructor(private commonServiceProvider: CommonServiceProvider, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) { }
  setupDB() {
    this.db = new PouchDB('Contacts');
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.setupDB();  //DB Setup
    // Function to check if doc is exixts in DB or not
    this.db.allDocs({
      include_docs: true,
      attachments: true
    }, function (err, response) {
      if (!err) {
        //if DB don't have any doc, call the contact service to fatch data
        if (response.total_rows == 0) {
          this.commonServiceProvider.fetchContacts()
            .subscribe((data: any) => {
              if (data.responseCode === 0) {
                this.itemsList = data.contacts;
                // Insert service data in DB
                this.db.bulkDocs(data.contacts, (err, result) => {
                  if (!err) {
                  }else{
                    console.log(err);
                  }
                });
              } else { }
            }, err => {
              console.log(err);
            });
        } else {
          this.itemsList = response.rows;
        }
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using arrow function here `this.db.allDocs({
  include_docs: true,
  attachments: true
}, function (err, response) {`

Comment: @yurzui Can you show me how to use arrow for this call back?

Comment: It should look like `this.db.allDocs({
      include_docs: true,
      attachments: true
    }, (err, response) => {` I removed `function` keyword and add arrow right after params